# XML parsing with ElementTree produces wrong output

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to parse an XML file with ElementTree but at a certain tag the output is wrong

```
<descriptions>
<description descriptionType="Abstract">Some Abstract Text
</description>
</descriptions>
```

So I parse it with the XML function

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
root = ElementTree.XML(my_xml)
root.getchildren()[0].items()
```

and the outcome is:

```
Out: [('descriptionType', 'Abstract')]
```

Is there any problem with the XML, I use ElementTree in a wrong way or it's a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just that if there are no tags its stored in the text attribute..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get the text.  So:

```
root.getchildren()[0].text
```

not

```
root.getchildren()[0].items()
```

Comment: yeah I realised that afterwards. thanx!

Comment: I answered the same thing before you :-/

Comment: Ha.  My answer's better!  But seriously, this isn't just for you, it's for other people reading the question later as well.  So you could mark yours as correct if you like.  Then everyone knows what the answer is.  p.s. But you're right, I wanted the points.  That's gamification: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html